# how to echo line breaks mysql row

Tags: php, html

I have quotes in MySql Database which have line breaks like below.

```
First Line
Second Line
```

But its showing me in my page like this

```
First Line Second Line
```

My Code is like below

```
<td><?php echo $row['qu_text'];?></td>
```

What I am missing ?

Thanks

Comment: use `nl2br()` ..

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid How can I use it with my above code ? Sorry, I am learning yet !

Comment: You're missing the fact that HTML treats line breaks as whitespace, an compresses all consecutive whitespace characters to a single space.... HTML uses a `<br />` tag to represent a line break

Comment: @MarkBaker I have 18000+ Quotes in my database...I think changing it is very hard. You have any suggestion for me to solve my issue ? Thanks

Comment: Don't change them in your database, change them when you want to display them.... and you've already been told how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML doesn't render `\n` as a newline, try replacing with `<br>` using this built in PHP function:

```
nl2br($text);
```

Or in your case:

```
echo nl2br($row['qu_text']);
```

See the [PHP documentation on nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php) for more info

Comment: Hi ! Thanks its working fine :)

Comment: @PareshSharma If this answer is correct, please mark it correct using the check mark under the downvote button!

Comment: Well copied from the first comment to the answer which states exactly what this answer is about...

Comment: I will do it...its showing that I can accept it in 4 minutes.

Comment: @PareshSharma Ah, okay. Thank you!